# how to replace all but one character in a set of identifcal strings (different character stays not replaced in each string)?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a character vector of identical elements:

```
vec <- c("AXAXAXA", "AXAXAXA", "AXAXAXA")
```

I would like to replace "X" with "Y" but leave one "X" behind in each string, different one in each string, so I get

```
vec_res <- c("AXAYAYA", "AYAXAYA", "AYAYAXA")
```

The strings are always the same and the number of elements (strings) in the vector is the same as the number of "X" in each string

I am new to `sringr` but I suspect there could be a smart way to do this.

Comment: How generalization does this need to be? All strings have the same length and the same number of Xs? The total length of the vector is always exactly equal to the number of Xs?

Comment: added the description. All elements of the vector are the same and the number of elements in the vector is equal to the number of "X" in each string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one

```
x <- 'AXAXAXA'
y <- grepRaw('X', x, all = TRUE)
x <- chartr('X', 'Y', rep(x, length(y)))
substr(x, y, y + 1) <- 'X'
x
# [1] "AXAYAYA" "AYAXAYA" "AYAYAXA"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option utilizing `purrr` could be:

```
map2_chr(.x = grepRaw("X", vec[1], all = TRUE),
         .y = vec,
         ~ `substr<-`(gsub("X", "Y", .y), .x, .x, "X"))

[1] "AXAYAYA" "AYAXAYA" "AYAYAXA"
```

The same thing with `base R`:

```
mapply(function(x, y) `substr<-`(gsub("X", "Y", y), x, x, "X"),
       x = grepRaw("X", vec[1], all = TRUE),
       y = vec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a very common operator or that stringr will help much here. Here's a base R function. Since the repetition of the input vector is redundant, this function expects a single value and will generate an output value for each of the X's

```
swap_expand <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(length(x)==1)
  m <- gregexpr("X", x)
  regmatches(x, m) <- "Y"  #set all X's to Y
  m <- m[[1]]
  r <- rep(x, length(m))   #repeat for each X
  substr(r, m, m)<-"X"     #replace a different Y each time
  r
}

swap_expand("AXAXAXA")
# [1] "AXAYAYA" "AYAXAYA" "AYAYAXA"
```